# How do you make an identifier out of concatenated strings in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, identifier

Basically I want to turn a string in to an identifier for an object like so:

```
count = 0
for i in range(50):
   count += 1
   functionToMakeIdentifier("foo" + str(count)) = Object(init_variable)
```

I want to make a series of objects with names like foo1, foo2, foo3, foo4, foo5, etc... But I don't know how to turn those strings into identifiers for the objects. Help!

Comment: The same question for Ruby: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4370084/ruby-is-it-possible-to-set-the-value-of-a-instance-variable-where-the-instance-v

Comment: Why on Earth do you think you need this?

Comment: Why would I need this? If I want to make 50 objects, or a million for that matter, without typing out the name of every single one!

Comment: Please read an introductory programming text, and learn what an array is.

Comment: @user539718, I think you're reading too much into Glenn's comment. This is a site dedicated to helping people with their programming problems. We can't assume any level of knowledge here. Your problem is solved by using an array, and in fact what you are trying to accomplish is the whole idea behind arrays. That is why Glenn pointed you to reading about them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**You don't.** You use an array (aka list in Python), or a dictionary if you want/need to use something more fancy than consecutive integers (e.g. strings) for identifying the individual items.

For example:

```
foos = []
count = 0
for i in range(50):
   count += 1
   foos.append(Object(init_variable))
```

Afterwards, you can refer to the first `foo` as `foos[0]` and the 50th `foo` as `foo[49]` (indices start at 0 - sure seems weird, but once you get used to it, it's at least as fine as long as everybody agrees on one thing -- and Python encourages 0-based indices, e.g. `range` counts from 0).

Also, your code can be simplified further. If you just want to generate a list of `Object` instances, you can use list comprehension (will propably take a while until your class or book or tutorial covers this...). Also, in your specific example, `count` and `i` are identical and can thus be merged (and when you want to count along something you iterate like `for item in items: ...`, you can use `for count, item in enumerate(items)`).

Comment: Ah ha, the list does make sense. Thank you for your detailed answer.

Answer (score 3):

Do this instead:

```
foos = [Object(init_variable) for _ in range(50)]
print(foos[0]) # first item
```

You now have a list of 50 `Object` items.

Maybe, if you really want to use these `foo1` strings you could do

```
foo_dict = {'foo%d'.format(i) : Object(init_variable) for i in range(1,51)]
print(foo_dict['foo1'])
```

Answer (score 2):

Your use case is absurd as one would use an array for that... but supposing you have a real need for it then the trick is using

```
globals()[name] = value
```

Answer (score 1):

are you looking for a dictionary?

you can do this:

```
foos = {}
for i in range(50):
   foos['foo%d' % i] = MyObject()
```

and create a dict with `keys()` like `['foo1', 'foo2', ...]` to access your objects.

Answer (score 0):

Use the **exec** function:

```
>>> for i in range(50):
...    count += 1
...    exec("foo%d = %d" % (count,count))
... 
>>> foo1
1
>>> foo2
2
>>> foo3
3
```

Comment: Technically it works, but it
simply horrible code. Therefore -1 for suggesting it.

Comment: You can be certain I will make use of Python's more dynamic features, whenever they are the best solution. In this case, they aren't -- not even remotely.

Comment: Exec will do the trick there, but it's an expensive call, and not really the "right" way to do this.

Comment: Expensive call for 50 elements, you dare not say that.

Comment: This might be what the OP asked for, but you're just setting him up for the next question: "How do i loop over variables `foo<n>` ?"

Comment: Premature optimization aside, it's 173 times slower in my quick'n'dirty `timeit` measurement. It had to be a whole lot cleaner to justify this kick to scalability's groin; but it's actually unspeakably more dirty. Ergo, another reason why it's about the worst possible solution.

Comment: Well I solved the original question, didn't modify the question. I get what I deserved in exchange. -2 points, meh :)

Comment: @delnan, takes 0.025 seconds here with python 2.6.1, if you optimized it 173 times, kudos to you.

Comment: It's a horrid solution to a non-problem. The non-problem has better and less horrid solutions as well.